# Opencv Error Using cv::ml::StatModel::calcError with Models Trained on Selected Feature Subset

Tags: c++, opencv

Using Opencv 3.2.0, I am trying to calculate the training and test error on an SVM model that was created with a subset of features by using the varIdx vector in cv::ml::TrainData::create(). Here is the relevant section of the c++ code.

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;
using namespace std;

// Code to read samples and responses from external data file not shown...

 // Copy vector to Mat
Mat matSamples(samples.size(), samples.at(0).size(), CV_32F);
for(int i = 0; i < matSamples.rows; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < matSamples.cols; j++) {
      matSamples.at<float>(i, j) = samples.at(i).at(j);
  }
}

// Copy vector to Mat
Mat matResponses(responses.size(), 1, CV_32SC1);
for(int i = 0; i < matResponses.rows; i++) {
      matResponses.at<int>(i) = responses.at(i);
}

// Create Mat to specify training variables (features)
Mat matVarIdx(1, 7, CV_32SC1);
matVarIdx = (Mat_<int>(1, 7) << 0, 15, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31);
cout << "Using features specified by " << matVarIdx << endl;

// Construct training data from samples read from file above
Ptr<TrainData> td = TrainData::create(
                    matSamples,                 // Array of samples
                    ROW_SAMPLE,                 // Data in rows
                    matResponses,               // Array of responses
                    matVarIdx,                  // Use features specified
                    noArray(),                  // Use all data points
                    noArray(),                  // Do not use samples weights
                    noArray()                   // Do not specify inp and out types
                    );

// Split training and test data
double ratio = 0.90; // 90% of samples will be labled training data
bool shuffle = true; // randomly shuffle test and training data
td->setTrainTestSplitRatio(ratio, shuffle);
int n_train_samples = td->getNTrainSamples();
int n_test_samples  = td->getNTestSamples();

cout << "Found " << n_train_samples << " Train Samples, and "
     << n_test_samples << " Test Samples." << endl;

// Output number of features
cout << "Total number of features " << td->getNAllVars() << " and "
     << td->getNVars() << " features used." << endl;

// Set up SVM's parameters
Ptr<SVM> svm = SVM::create();
svm->setType(SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(SVM::RBF);
svm->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 1000, FLT_EPSILON));

// Train the SVM with given parameters
svm->train(td);

// Calculate errors.
Mat results;
float train_performance = svm->StatModel::calcError(
                                         td,
                                         false, // use train data
                                         results);

cout << "Incorrectly classified training samples: " << train_performance << "%" << endl;

float test_performance = svm->StatModel::calcError(
                                        td,
                                        true, // use test data
                                        results);

cout << "Incorrectly classified test samples: " << test_performance << "%" << endl;
```

Here's the output of the program:

```
Using features specified by [0, 15, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31]
Found 267 Train Samples, and 30 Test Samples.
Total number of features 32 and 7 features used.
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F) in predict, file /home/lindo/dev/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp, line 1930
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/lindo/dev/opencv/opencv-3.2.0/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp:1930: error: (-215) samples.cols == var_count && samples.type() == CV_32F in function predict
Aborted
```

It looks like the predictions used to calculate the errors failed because the number of sample columns isn't equal to the number of features which is what I intended to set by using varIdx in creating the training data.

This code works when I use the full number of features, i.e, set varIdx = cv::noArray() in cv:ml::TrainData::create().

I've tried to use a vector instead of a Mat for varIdx as well as using a CV_8UC1 Mat for varIdx but still get the same assertion error.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ml/doc/mldata.html), it is explained that the varIdx vector is used to identify features of interest and working as a list of 0-based indices or a mask of active variables

This way, you may consider creating a varIdx vector number_of_features-sized and giving either 0 or 1 values for variables you want to be taken into account or not.

I think that your error occurred because varIdx was containing only 7 values instead of 32 and that at prediction time OpenCV was expecting only 7 but was given 32. This error doesn't occur when you don't specify variables of interest because the algorithm takes every variable into account with equal weight.

Also don't hesitate to take a look a the code of the library. Your compiler gave you the place where the error happened so it may help you to understand why your code fail.